# Count the Ocurrences of Substring in whole File

Tags: linux, shell, awk

For example, I have a file log.txt, the content may be

```
GetData() starts                 2014-11-30 17:05   
GetData(100) ends                2014-11-30 17:05     
printf("") starts                2014-11-30 17:05 
printf() ends                    2014-11-30 17:06
UpdateScreen(xxx) starts         2014-11-30 17:06
UpdateScreen(xx) end             2014-11-30 17:06
GetData() starts                 2014-11-30 17:06
GetData(100) ends                2014-11-30 17:06
```

for each function name, I want to count the occurrences in the whole file, and output the statistics into output.txt.

```
output:
GetData: 4
Printf: 2
UpdateScreen: 2
```

How to do that via linux shell commands like awk?

**Update**
**The text in () are parameters passed into functions**, thus they are dynamic, which means calls to a same GetData may leave different logs such as GetData(5) ends, or GetData(100) or GetData(1000). This is also the same to other functions.

I wanna to get total count of each function, thus GetData(2) and GetData(100) shall count as a same type of GetData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
$ awk -F"(" '{count[$1]++} END{for ( i in count) print i": "count[i]}' input
UpdateScreen: 2
GetData: 4
printf: 2
```

**What it does?**

- `-F"("` sets the field separator as `(`
- `count[$1]++` creats an array `count` indexed by column 1, `$1` the function name
- `for ( i in count) print i": "count[i]}` prints the content of the array

Comment: I want to get a substring ( e.g. FunctionName+'(' ) of $1 and get its occurrences, how to achieve that? The reason for this is: "The text in () are dynamic, which means calls to a same GetData may leave different logs such as GetData(5) ends, or GetData(100) or GetData(1000). This is also the same to other functions."

Comment: @Steve you mean to get separate counts for GetData(5) GetData(100) and so on or single count for the entire GetData

Comment: I wanna get the single count for GetData and all other functions, so I need to split the function name from $1 and search through the whole file, other than use the $1 directly. How to do that?

Comment: @Steve sorry i didnt get you clearly. The answer performs *I wanna to get total count of each function, thus GetData(2) and GetData(100) shall count as a same type of GetData* right? If not can you please provide an example?

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice the part "-F"("". You r right, I will accept your answer：——）

Comment: @Steve Its alright :) . I was worried that i didnt understand the qs correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '^\w+' input | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > output.txt
```

1. grep ... - gets the function names
2. sort | uniq -c   - counts the Ocurrences
3. sort -nr - order them occurences